# splice array base on property value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.myJson = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "banana",
    "price": 12,
    "qty": 3,
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "watermelon",
    "price": 12.9,
    "qty": 4,
  }];

for(i = 0; i < $scope.myJson.length; i++) {
      if($scope.myJson[i]._id == '2'){

        //what to do here?
        //then save back to localstorage
      }
    }
```

I'm using localstorage so I have to find array and splice it. I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Splice is the worst option in terms of performance. 
Yet in your case you would need to do:

`$scope.myJson.splice(i,1);`

See performance comparison here: https://jsperf.com/splice-vs-filter

I would at least do a filter:

`$scope.myJson = $scope.myJson.filter(function(obj) {
 return (obj.id !== '2');
}) ;`

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the array, search for the desired property value and splice the array.

```
function spliced(array, value) {
    var arr = array.slice(0);


    array.forEach(function (obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
            if (obj['id'] == value ) {
                arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj),1);
            }
        }
    });
    return arr;
}

console.log( spliced(arr, 1) )
```

Comment: I like your solution, but one question: why do you return `arr`? (i.e., `array.slice(0)`). Why not simply return `array`?